# Pegar caracteres específicos de uma string?

Tags: javascript, string, email

Estou recebendo a seguinte String em Javascript:

```
Nome Sobrenome <email@email.com>
```

Como faço para pegar somente o email que está dentro de `<>`??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podes usar uma regex para isso, ou `String.slice`.

Seria algo assim:

```js
var string = 'Nome Sobrenome <email@email.com>';


var varianteA = string.slice(
  string.indexOf('<') + 1,
  string.indexOf('>')
);
console.log(varianteA);

var varianteB = string.match(/<([^>]+)>/);
varianteB = varianteB ? varianteB[1] : '';
console.log(varianteB);
```

Sobre a regex:

- `<` no inicio da parte a encontrar
- `(` marcador de inicio de grupo de captura
- `[^>]+` - tudo menos `>` 1 ou mais vezes
- `)` marcador de final de grupo de captura
- `>` final da parte a encontrar na string

Depois usei `varianteB = varianteB ? varianteB[1] : '';` caso não haver `match` e evitar erros antes de tentar aceder a `varianteB[1]` se o match der `null`.

Comment: Vou testar e já falo o que aconteceu

Comment: Sergio, só por curiosidade, teria alguma maneira de na própria regex remover os caracteres `<` e `>` ? Estou tentando aqui e não consigo de jeito nenhum... x.x

Comment: Já está sendo pelo o que vi executando o código acima...

Comment: @MathiasFalci sim, mas seria mais trabalhoso, neste caso é mais simples excluir `<>` que incluir os caracteres válidos. Mas sim, seria algo assim (com reserva para eventuais caracteres em falta): `'Nome Sobrenome <email@email.com>'.match(/[a-z\d_\-.]+@[a-z\d_\-.]+/)[0]`

Comment: @Sergio Perfeito, obrigado pelo esclarecimento. @LeonardoEbert sim, está sendo, mas para isso o Sergio pegou o grupo de correspondência `varianteB[1]`, eu estava tentando fazer isso diretamente na regex.

Comment: Ok, entendi... É que não entendo muito dessse negócio de RegEx...

Comment: Quanto à resposta do @Sergio, é só questão de adaptar aos dados que vem do servidor para o cliente, e vou me empenhar nisso agora... Mais uma vez, muito obrigado Sergio

Comment: @LeonardoEbert de nada. Expliquei mais sobre a regex caso seja útil.

Comment: Mais conhecimento sempre é útil...

Answer (score 3):

Pode usar `regex`...

```js
 alert("<email@email.com>".match(/\<([^)]+)\>/)[1]);
```

Vou postar pq já tinha começado @Sergio é muito rápido

Comment: Vou testar pra ver o que vai resultar...